# Can a windows form display the min and max buttons without the close button?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is there any way (in C#) to display a form with just the minimise and maximise buttons? Without the close button?

The only way of removing the close button (that I'm aware of) is:

```
form.ControlBox = false;
```

But this also gets rid of both the other buttons.

Comment: there is also form.MaximizeBox and form.MinimizeBox - you can try disabling Control and enabling those two.  Not sure if it works so I can't answer for sure.

Comment: Have you ever seen a window of any sort on your Windows machine that had minimize and maximize but not close?  I think you'll need to  owner draw your own non-client area with whatever buttons you want.

Comment: @jeffamaphone:  I have, actually.  I don't remember what program had it though.

Comment: @jeffamaphone I use a minimize-only windows (without a maximize/close) for things like updater windows. If the user wants to cancel the update they have to click on the "zomg abort! abort!" button.

Comment: @SB "But this also gets rid of both the other buttons."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a function to do this once

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(this.Handle, 0), SC_CLOSE, MF_GRAYED) == -1)
            throw new Win32Exception("The message box did not exist to gray out its X");
    }
    private const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
    private const int MF_GRAYED = 0x1;
    [DllImport("USER32")]
    internal static extern int EnableMenuItem(IntPtr WindowHandle, int uIDEnableItem, int uEnable);
    [DllImport("USER32")]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr WindowHandle, int bReset);
}
```

Note alt-f4 still works and right click "close this window" when you are looking at it from the task bar. (tested in windows 7)

Comment: Add a button and in its Click event set ShowInTaskbar to false to see this fail.

Answer (score 2):

There's an article [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/itsraj007/Rajendra105292008020242AM/Rajendra1.aspx) showing how to do that. It requires using the unmanaged User32.dll

Comment: Important notes: However, in my experience (Windows 7), that approach "grays" the close button (it doesn't technically remove it) and *does not prevent* the normal Alt+F4 behavior (but you can abort the is-closing for that). You can remove the Min/Max boxes through the window-style, but I think to *completely* remove the close box requires handling the window painting.